# Django-filter hide/remove filter field

Tags: django, filter, field, hide, django-filter

i am using Django-filter by Alex, and i want remove some fields from filter form in view.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
for name, field in self.filter.filters.iteritems():      
    if somethink:
        if name == "price":
            field.visible = False
```

Here is my code:

filter:

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['price', 'release_date']
```

and then SingleTableView:

```
class ProductTableView(SingleTableView):
  filter_class = ProductFilter


  def get_table_data(self, **kwargs):
    queryset =super(ProductTableView, self).get_table_data()
    self.filter = self.filter_class(self.request.GET,  queryset=queryset)
    return self.filter

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProductTableView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    for name, field in self.filter.filters.iteritems():      
        if somethink:
            if name == "price":
                field.visible = False

    context['filter'] = self.filter
    return context
```

I know that I can do it in template, but this is better option for me. I need change filter based on User role

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your code I'm guessing here, but have you tried specifying the fields you want to filter on via the `Meta` class?

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['price', 'release_date']
```

Then in your view:

```
def product_list(request):
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('my_app/template.html', {'filter': f})
```

This will only allow the `price` and `release_date` fields to be filtered on/viewed.

Link to [relevant documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).